# android soft keyboard popup character

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am developing android soft keyboard, I have problem in popup layout of characters.
[image]
  In picture above @ is popup character of #.if user long press on # the @ appears.

My problem: I want if user touch outside of @ character or press back button of device the popup (@) disappear but it is appear until user press @.
How can i do that?

Comment: is it a custom keyboard you've build or the system keyboard? You cannot change much in the system keyboard. For such features write your own keyboard.

Comment: is is custom keyboard which i developed myself.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to override `onTouchEvent` to detect gesture and hide the popup view. Popup characters use custom layout which specified in your Keyboard layout (XML) with `android:keyPreviewLayout` tag.

See the example below for `onTouchEvent`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch(action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                    "of current screen element");
            return true;
        default :
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```